# muitiple CRON jobs not working with Node js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cron

whenever i put this expression in `CloudWatchRule` `"cron(1,5 9 * * ? *)"`. it runs only for 09:01. When 09: 05  , it is not trigger the lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

If You are creating the rules then EventBridge is now the featured service for that.
I put Your's CRON expression as the schedule pattern and got this output:
[image]

I never had a situation that the rule was not triggered at a specific time when set everything up correctly.

Are You sure that the lambda was not triggered at 9:05?
Maybe validate the CRON expression?

Comment: I saw in cloudwatch logs. where it shows for first time log. but no log generate for second time

Comment: same function, same handler.

Comment: If the first call takes longer then 5 min and the parallelization factor is 1 then the second function is not being called. Can this be the case?

Comment: There have no possibility. because i have the log after 1 min

Comment: Here You can find possible solutions: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eventbridge-lambda-not-triggered/

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the reason. I manually provide permission.